# No matching generic delegate as lambda parameter in inheritance class

Tags: c++, c++11, arduino

I try use delegates in my project, but while coding deeper and deepeer I bump in some strange behavior.

Here maximum simplified code which show my problem:

```
template<typename T>
class Slave{
    public:
    typedef void (*F)(T option);

    Slave<T>::F f;

    Slave(Slave<T>::F *f){
        this->f = f;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Master {
    public:
    T option;
    Slave<T>* slave;

    Master(T option, Slave<T>* slave){
        this->option = option;
        this->slave = slave;
    }
    void blink(){
        slave->f(option);
    }
};

void loop(){
    Master<int> *m;
    m = new Master<int>(3, new Slave<int>([](int option) -> void {
        //blink option times
    })); // Here error: no matching function for call to 'Slave<int>::Slave(Core::Core()::<lambda(int)>)'
    m->blink();
};
```

Comment: `Slave<T>::F*` is a pointer to a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem it that `Slave<T>::F` is already a pointer.

```
Slave(Slave<T>::F *f){
    this->f = f;
}
```

Your parameter is a pointer to a pointer to a function. Simply change it to that:

```
Slave(Slave<T>::F f){
    this->f = f;
}
```

Comment: better yet, `Slave(F f) : f(f) {}`

Comment: NathanOliver, yep, but real code greatly bigger than this piece of code

Comment: Guillaume Racicot shame on me, sorry for disturbing! Where devastate button?

Comment: @WildBraas I don't recommend deletion of this question